# "Die Bank hat zu" translation?

Tags: translation

This sentence is one of the Lingvist flashcards.

Google Translate says it means "The bank has to" but that doesn't make sense assuming it's a full sentence.

I did try to figure out the meaning outside of Google Translate. If you look up "*zu*" you'll see it defined as "in, towards, to, close to, for, for which, ...".

Is there another translation? Maybe "The bank is open"?
It would be nice if Lingvist provided translations.

Comment: *hat zu* means *ist geschlossen*

Comment: I vote for not admitting questions that are based on silly stuff coming out of Google Translate. People should apply a minimal but reasonable amount of effort to find a solution. Google Translate is not an effort.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Google Translate may be bad - but is everybody aware of that?

Comment: I did try to figure out the meaning outside of Google Translate. If you look up 'zu' you'll see it defined as 'in, towards, to, close to, for, for which'... It's odd that it's being used to mean 'closed'.

Comment: Hello Natalie, if you did additional research (beyond "Google Translate") it is a good idea to present your findings as part of your question. Seeing what you found and understood does also help us to give you a better, tailored answer. - By the way, I cannot imagine any dictionary (that deserves that name) to not mention for "zu" the meaning of "closed".

Comment: See second-to-last single word entry here: https://www.dict.cc/?s=zu

Comment: @Olafant https://www.dwds.de/wb/zu#2 does, as do https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zu#Adverb, https://en.langenscheidt.com/german-english/zu, https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/zu, etc. I withdrew my first comment here (suggesting to check a dictionary first) right after I wrote it mainly because on second thought I realised that probably not all dictionaries specifically mention the _haben_ alternative, but it's not like it can't be found in dictionaries ...

Comment: @johnl Ok. You're right. It's there. Sorry. Didn't expect that and didn't find it in the examples that you linked first.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann My apologies. I will be sure to do so in the future. Interglot was the dictionary I used that does not list 'closed' as a definition. https://m.interglot.com/de/en/zu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are here in the interesting area of "tiny words used especially in oral communication"

**zu = closed**

> Die Bank ist zu. Das Geschäft hat zu. Das Museum macht gleich zu. Der Freizeitpark wird zugemacht. Der Metzger ist zu gewesen, darum habe ich Fisch gekauft.

***aus* as well as *alle* = finished / not any more existing / spent / consumed / eaten up / depleted**

> Die Marmelade ist aus. Das Geld ist aus. Uns ist das Geld ausgegangen. Mir geht die Gelduld aus. Alles ist aus!
>
> Das Brot ist alle. Das Benzin ist alle. Jetzt mach mal deinen Kakao alle, und dann gehen wir.  Dich mach' ich alle!

Answer (score 6):

Wie Du auf [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Die%20Bank%20hat%20zu.) leicht herausfinden kannst, heißt es soviel wie "Die Bank ist zu." Statt "ist zu" "hat zu" zu sagen ist kein feines Hochdeutsch, aber sehr verbreitet.

Die Formulierungen

- hat geschlossen
- hat geöffnet

sind auch sehr verbreitet. Bei Institutionen ist es gängige Ausdrucksweise, aber nicht bei Räumen. In den eigenen vier Wänden würde niemand sagen "Die Küche hat zu", um auszudrücken, dass die Tür verschlossen ist, aber ein Kellner in einem Gasthof, nachts um halb zwölf, schon, um damit auszudrücken, dass kein Essen mehr bestellt werden kann. Die Stellung der Tür ist dabei völlig unerheblich.

Comment: **Going to have to use Google Translate for this** -1 for this incomprehensible answer. @Natalie you could ask user unknown nicely, if he were to provide a translation for this otherwise good answer.

Comment: Hat das noch was mit Hochdeutsch zu tun? *zu* ist doch ziemlich sicher eine Ellipse; Ich vermute mal: *zu-ge-schlossen*. Wenn man "hat" sagt, könnte "Die Bank" figurativ für irgendwelche beauftragte Person sein. Wenn eine Person die Institution darstellt, ist es kaum figurativ: *Der Schmied hat heute zu, weil Besuch kam*. Für Räume, Kisten, jegliche Zu- oder Durchgänge aller art kann man "ist" verwenden: *Der Schornstein ist zu* (verstopft), *mach die Tür zu* (regional auch *das Brett ran / zu*). Das letzte sieht kaum nach Ellipse aus und hat den entscheidenden direktionalen Character.

Comment: zudem gibt es einige regionale, teils historische Unterschiede der Hilfsverben. Dazu fehlt mir aber der Überblick. Kannst du das also bitte nicht so im vorbeigehen erwähnen, als sollte es selbstverständlich sein? English kennt übrigens auch beide Varianten, *has closed, is closed* und zeigt damit schon den Unterschied, auf den du wohl hinaus wolltest, denn "Die B ist seit drei Wochen zu[geschlossen]" ist variabel, aber nicht so "Die Bank hat vor drei Wochen zugemacht"